# Why does this series converge to this specific value?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Can someone show me why the sum of:

[image: sum]

converges to:

[image: converges to]

???

I just don't understand how to go between those two. (Or, if the answer is wrong, could someone help me understand what the right answer would be?)

Much appreciated!

Comment: This seems to be related to the Fourier series of a specific function.

Comment: Can you explain what context you found this sum?

Comment: @JonathanDavidson Calculating a second-order energy shift of the ground state of a certain infinite square well (i.e., perturbation theory in quantum mechanics).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, $$\cos^2\left(\frac{m\pi}2\right) = \cases{1 & if $m$ is even\cr 0 & if $m$ is odd}$$
so with $m=2k$ your sum becomes
$$ \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(4k^2-1)^3} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2k-1)^3(2k+1)^3} $$
Expand in partial fractions:
$$ \frac{1}{(2k-1)^3 (2k+1)^3} = \frac{3}{16}\; \frac{1}{ 2\,k-1}
-\frac{3}{16}\; \frac{1}{2k+1}-\frac{3}{16}\; \frac{1}{( 2\,k+1) ^{2}}-\frac{3}{16}\; \frac{1}{\left( 2\,k-1 \right) ^{2}}
-\frac{1}{8}\frac{1}{(2k+1)^3} + \frac{1}{8} \frac{1}{(2k-1)^3} 
$$
The sums of $\frac{3}{16} \frac{1}{2k-1} - \frac{3}{16} \frac{1}{2k+1}$ and $-\frac{1}{8}\frac{1}{(2k+1)^3} + \frac{1}{8} \frac{1}{(2k-1)^3}$ telescope, while 
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2k-1)^2} =  \frac{\pi^2}{8}$$ is well-known.

Comment: For context, the well-known sum is found by evaluating the Fourier series of a triangle wave function at a specific point.

Comment: @JonathanDavidson I appreciate the context!